# Need div to return to previous background color with JavaScript (no jquery)

Tags: javascript

I am close to finishing this but as a relative noobie to JavaScript I am not quite there. I have created a pop-up to alert users that their session will time out. While the pop-up is up, I am turning the DIV on the main page to have a background color of gray. Once the pop-up goes away, I want the DIV to return to its original state. I have tried using a `setTimeout`, but I am doing it incorrectly. It would also be nice to know how to make the "Continue Session" button make the pop-up go away.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('alert-trigger');
  button.addEventListener('click', addAlert);
});

function addAlert(event) {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
  var template = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
  example.innerHTML = template;
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '<div><span style="display:inline-block;width:28px;height:28px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67-title" viewBox="0 0 48 48" focusable="false"><title>Timeout Warning</title><path class="svgMainColor-yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67" d="M 32.4 29.15 h 3.53 l -0.47 9.73 h -2.53 Z m 0.17 12.51 a 1.59 1.59 0 1 1 3.19 0 a 1.59 1.59 0 0 1 -3.19 0 Z m 0.5 -20.77 a 1.28 1.28 0 0 1 2.27 0 l 12.51 23.65 a 1.51 1.51 0 0 1 0 1.37 a 1.38 1.38 0 0 1 -1.1 0.74 h -25 a 1.44 1.44 0 0 1 -1.14 -2.06 Z m -13.4 19.73 a 17.73 17.73 0 1 1 19.7 -17.73 l 3.11 5.89 a 21.45 21.45 0 0 0 0.8 -5.78 a 21.64 21.64 0 1 0 -25.54 21.27 Z M 13.12 30 l -1.51 -2.6 l 9.21 -5.34 V 11.88 h 3 l 0.01 11.92 Z" / ></svg></span><p>For your security, this session is about to end due to inactivity.</p><button id="contBtn" type="button">Continue Session</button></div>';
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '';
  }, 10000);
}

function setBgColorById(id, sColor) {
  var elem;
  if (document.getElementById) {
    if (elem = document.getElementById(id)) {
      if (elem.style) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = sColor;
        return 1; // success
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // failure
}
```

```css
[role="alert"] {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

[role="alert"]:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" role="alert"></div>
<div id="e1">
  <h1>Testing Banner Timeout</h1>
  <p>This page is supposed to act like the home page. It will timeout after 10 seconds of inactivity.</p>
  <p>If you dismiss the banner before it reaches 10 seconds, you will be able to remain on this page for another 10 seconds, where the banner will appear once again. If you let the banner reach 0, you will be redirected to the login page.</p>
  <button id="alert-trigger" onclick="setBgColorById('e1','#848484');return false;">Display Session Manager</button>
</div>
```

Comment: add an eventListener to the button after you set it in '#example'

Comment: Mainly, you choosed bad approach to show the modal "window". Wait, I create answer with example based on your code.

Answer (score 0):

To reset the color of the page, you could use a click handler on your modal button, like this:

```
document.getElementById('contBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('e1').style.backgroundColor = "white";
});
```

When the modal button is clicked, the page background resets to white (or whatever color you want to use).

Here's a (slightly streamlined) working example, which also hides the modal when the modal button is clicked:

```js
var example = document.getElementById('example');

document.getElementById('contBtn').addEventListener('click', hideModal); // hide modal on click

function addAlert(event) {
  setTimeout(hideModal, 10000); // hide modal on timeout
}

function setBgColorById(id, sColor) {
  if (example.style.display == "inline-block") { // if modal already visible
    return;
  }
  example.style.display = "inline-block";
  addAlert();
  var elem;
  if (document.getElementById) {
    if (elem = document.getElementById(id)) {
      if (elem.style) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = sColor;
        return 1; // success
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // failure
}

function hideModal() { // hide modal on click or timeout
  document.getElementById('e1').style.backgroundColor = "white"; // reset background color
  example.style.display = "none"; // hide modal
}
```

```css
[role="alert"] {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" role="alert">
  <div>
    <span style="display:inline-block;width:28px;height:28px;">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67-title" viewBox="0 0 48 48" focusable="false"><title>Timeout Warning</title><path class="svgMainColor-yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67" d="M 32.4 29.15 h 3.53 l -0.47 9.73 h -2.53 Z m 0.17 12.51 a 1.59 1.59 0 1 1 3.19 0 a 1.59 1.59 0 0 1 -3.19 0 Z m 0.5 -20.77 a 1.28 1.28 0 0 1 2.27 0 l 12.51 23.65 a 1.51 1.51 0 0 1 0 1.37 a 1.38 1.38 0 0 1 -1.1 0.74 h -25 a 1.44 1.44 0 0 1 -1.14 -2.06 Z m -13.4 19.73 a 17.73 17.73 0 1 1 19.7 -17.73 l 3.11 5.89 a 21.45 21.45 0 0 0 0.8 -5.78 a 21.64 21.64 0 1 0 -25.54 21.27 Z M 13.12 30 l -1.51 -2.6 l 9.21 -5.34 V 11.88 h 3 l 0.01 11.92 Z" / ></svg>
    </span>
    <p>For your security, this session is about to end due to inactivity.</p>
    <button id="contBtn" type="button">Continue Session</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="e1">
  <h1>Testing Banner Timeout</h1>
  <p>This page is supposed to act like the home page. It will timeout after 10 seconds of inactivity.</p>
  <p>If you dismiss the banner before it reaches 10 seconds, you will be able to remain on this page for another 10 seconds, where the banner will appear once again. If you let the banner reach 0, you will be redirected to the login page.</p>
  <button id="alert-trigger" onclick="setBgColorById('e1','#848484');return false;">Display Session Manager</button>
</div>
```

I moved the HTML for your modal into the HTML section, rather than adding it with JavaScript; feel free to move it back if you want. I also removed a couple of variables that weren't needed and shortened up some of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses on that. I sorta faked a modal and really appreciate seeing it done the right way.

Comment: The second version was what I was trying to achieve visually. Now to test with the screen reader and make sure it works OK.

Comment: Thank freginold. This functions like I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another event listener attached to `contBtn` in order to change your background color:

```
document.getElementById('contBtn').addEventListener('click', removeAlert);

function removeAlert(event) {
    // remove alert
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '';
    // update background color
    setBgColorById('e1','#fff');
    // remove event listener when there is no alert
    document.getElementById('contBtn').removeEventListener('click', removeAlert);
}
```

**Here is a working example**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById('alert-trigger');
  button.addEventListener('click', addAlert);
});

function addAlert(event) {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
  var template = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
  example.innerHTML = template;
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '<div><span style="display:inline-block;width:28px;height:28px;"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-labelledby="yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67-title" viewBox="0 0 48 48" focusable="false"><title>Timeout Warning</title><path class="svgMainColor-yui_3_18_1_1_1510613031292_67" d="M 32.4 29.15 h 3.53 l -0.47 9.73 h -2.53 Z m 0.17 12.51 a 1.59 1.59 0 1 1 3.19 0 a 1.59 1.59 0 0 1 -3.19 0 Z m 0.5 -20.77 a 1.28 1.28 0 0 1 2.27 0 l 12.51 23.65 a 1.51 1.51 0 0 1 0 1.37 a 1.38 1.38 0 0 1 -1.1 0.74 h -25 a 1.44 1.44 0 0 1 -1.14 -2.06 Z m -13.4 19.73 a 17.73 17.73 0 1 1 19.7 -17.73 l 3.11 5.89 a 21.45 21.45 0 0 0 0.8 -5.78 a 21.64 21.64 0 1 0 -25.54 21.27 Z M 13.12 30 l -1.51 -2.6 l 9.21 -5.34 V 11.88 h 3 l 0.01 11.92 Z" / ></svg></span><p>For your security, this session is about to end due to inactivity.</p><button id="contBtn" type="button">Continue Session</button></div>';
  
  // attach event listener to contBtn 
  document.getElementById('contBtn').addEventListener('click', removeAlert);
  
}


function removeAlert(event) {
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '';
    setBgColorById('e1','#fff');
    
    // remove event listener 
    document.getElementById('contBtn').removeEventListener('click', removeAlert);
}

function setBgColorById(id, sColor) {
  var elem;
  if (document.getElementById) {
    if (elem = document.getElementById(id)) {
      if (elem.style) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = sColor;
        return 1; // success
      }
    }
  }
  return 0; // failure
}
```

```css
[role="alert"] {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

[role="alert"]:empty {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" role="alert"></div>
<div id="e1">
  <h1>Testing Banner Timeout</h1>
  <p>This page is supposed to act like the home page. It will timeout after 10 seconds of inactivity.</p>
  <p>If you dismiss the banner before it reaches 10 seconds, you will be able to remain on this page for another 10 seconds, where the banner will appear once again. If you let the banner reach 0, you will be redirected to the login page.</p>
  <button id="alert-trigger" onclick="setBgColorById('e1','#848484');return false;">Display Session Manager</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need some sort of overlay and not color the background to gray. I may be wrong. 
Here is the snippet with some addition. you would get an idea.

```js
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('alert-trigger');
    if (button.addEventListener)
      button.addEventListener('click', addAlert);
  });

function addAlert(event) {
  var example = document.getElementById('example');
  var template = document.getElementById('example').innerHTML;
  var modal = document.getElementById('overlaydiv');
  modal.setAttribute('class','overlay');
  example.innerHTML = template;
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '<div class="modal"><span style="display:inline;width:28px;height:28px;border-color:red"><title>Timeout Warning</title></span><p>For your security, this session is about to end due to inactivity.</p><button id="contBtn" onclick="destroy()" type="button">Continue Session</button></div>';
  setTimeout(function() {
    destroy();
  }, 10000);
}


function destroy(){
   var modal = document.getElementById('overlaydiv');
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = '';
    modal.setAttribute('class','hidden');
 
}
```

```css
[role="alert"] {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

[role="alert"]:empty {
  display: none;
}

.overlay{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:gray;
opacity:0.9;
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
}

.modal{
width:200px;
height:200px;
border-color:red;
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:50px;
z-index:9999;
}

.hidden{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<div id="example" role="alert"></div>
<div id="e1">
  <h1>Testing Banner Timeout</h1>
  <p>This page is supposed to act like the home page. It will timeout after 10 seconds of inactivity.</p>
  <p>If you dismiss the banner before it reaches 10 seconds, you will be able to remain on this page for another 10 seconds, where the banner will appear once again. If you let the banner reach 0, you will be redirected to the login page.</p>
  <button id="alert-trigger" >Display Session Manager</button>
</div>
<div id="overlaydiv"  class="hidden"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Nilesh. I tested with JAWS 18/IE 11 and I am not hearing the alert dialog until after I close the session timeout warning--which is also what I am after. However, it works fine with Firefox and NVDA. I don't understand why--going to investigate.

Comment: Ok I fixed the problem with IE11. Looks like IE does not understand the ````"`" ```` symbol and I had to replace it with ````' ```` Now if you run the snippet it works